# Reporting Services Excel rendering extensions?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Our company has a reporting solution utilizing Analysis services + Reporting Services, with excel reports being a priority. Everything's sort of fine, but several annoying things are bothering us:

- No ability to rename the sheets
- Embedded images stretch the containing cells vertically, thus making scrolling a pain
- <strike>Cross-sheet links are not supported</strike> (turns out that can be implemented using bookmarks)

So my question is basically this - should we try solving these issues somehow (i.e. is that even possible), or should we use some excel rendering extension with more formatting options ? Can you recommend any extensions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Apose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/ssrs-rendering-extensions/aspose.cells-for-reporting-services/default.aspx).  I've never used their products, but you can download a free trial and see if it suits your needs.

Alternatively, you can create custom renderer [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163840.aspx)